# Get actual encoded url in Sinatra handler, splat broken

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack, urlencode

How do I get the actual encoded URL that was passed to my handler in Sinatra?

I have a url like - note there is / followed by a double slash that's encoded..

```
  http://someplace.com/thing/blah/%2F%2Fxxx.png

  get '/thing/*/*' do
    begin
      # would like this to work but it does not. Sinatra 1.4.4, ruby 2.0.0
      first = CGI.unescape(params[:splat][0])
      path = CGI.unescape(params[:splat][1])
      # path does NOT have a double // (%2F%2F), 
      # it has all of them ripped off by some rack code, I think

      # TRY get actual URL and parse by myself...
      the_url = request.url # this is already urldecoded and is missing the double //
      the_query_path = request.env["rack.request.query_string"]; # blank for me?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/issues/808

Ok - I know - that report was from me 6 months ago. As you can see they added protection on splats to stop attackers from getting at your file system.

in the app config section:

```
    set :protection, :except => :path_traversal
```

Now you lose that protection... In my case the paths are not on the same machine as the ruby server.

It would still be handy to know how to get the actual url that the server was hit with, likely some rack environment thing.